# Gradle - Changing artifactory repoKey based on buildType

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to change a repoKey based on the buildVariant. For instance, I want to set repoKey = "ProdRepo" for release build and repoKey = "DebugRepo" for debug build.

example:

```
artifactory {
    contextUrl = "http://url.com"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = *ProdRepo/DebugRepo* //based on buildType
            username = properties.getProperty('artifactory_username')
            password = properties.getProperty('artifactory_password')
            maven = true
        }

        defaults {
            publishArtifacts = true
            publishBuildInfo = true
            publishPom = true
            publications('aar')
        }
    }
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

OK, try adding a variable like :

```
def b_type
```

And in your `buildTypes` section give it a value for each type :

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
       ...
       b_type = "Debug"
    }
    release {
       ...
       b_type = "Prod"
    }
}
```

Finally use that in you key :

```
repoKey = "${b_type}Repo"
```

Comment: not working. it uses "ProdRepo" doesn't matter what build variant is selected

Comment: When you are building an apk file you can use build types. Normally, there is not a way to separate them @phnmnn

Comment: Are you using command line for publishing? If yes can you specify which gradle command/task you are running?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the below config.

**For Library**

```
artifactory {
        contextUrl = "http://url.com"
        publish {
            repository {
                android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
                    println(variant.getBuildType().name)
                    if(variant.getBuildType().name == "debug") {
                        repoKey = 'debug'
                    } else if(variant.getBuildType().name == "release") {
                        repoKey = 'release'
                    }
                }
                 username = properties.getProperty('artifactory_username')
                 password = properties.getProperty('artifactory_password')
                maven = true
            }

            defaults {
                publishArtifacts = true
                publishBuildInfo = true
                publishPom = true
                publications('aar')
            }
        }
    }
```

**For Application**

```
artifactory {
    contextUrl = "http://url.com"
    publish {
        repository {
            android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                println(variant.getBuildType().name)
                if(variant.getBuildType().name == "debug") {
                    repoKey = 'debug'
                } else if(variant.getBuildType().name == "release") {
                    repoKey = 'release'
                }
            }
             username = properties.getProperty('artifactory_username')
             password = properties.getProperty('artifactory_password')
            maven = true
        }

        defaults {
            publishArtifacts = true
            publishBuildInfo = true
            publishPom = true
            publications('aar')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could not get unknown property 'applicationVariants' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.

Comment: Is it possible to post your entire build gradle file for better understanding , the above answer is for normal android app. For library extension may have to tweak a little, but the idea remains the same

Comment: @phnmnn  Please see the updated answer.  since you are building it as library project should use android.libraryVariants instead of android.applicationVariants

Comment: on each build variant selection println(variant.getBuildType().name) prints both typebuild.

Comment: yes it will print as expected. but  repoKey = 'debug'  will assign only if debug  and  repoKey = 'release' will assign only if Release

Comment: both commands are executed on each build variant selection in same order...(on debug build type-> debug, release, same on release -> debug release.) so in fact last executed command is repoKey = 'release alltimes

Comment: You should be able to tweak this, further information can't provided. If you understood what this code does then you should be able to do minor changes.